# Why my content hides behind header in Ionic 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, uiview, header

I am new to angular and I have been trying to figure out what is causing the content to hide behind the header.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Cleaners</h1>
</div>

<ion-content ui-view>
</ion-content>

<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced"></div>
```

I don't want to use bootstrap, I am using actual Ionic components.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the class `class="has-header"` to `<ion-content>` tag

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    ....
</ion-content>
```

It should work fine.